# Android cursoroutofboundexception

Tags: android, cursor, contactscontract

I am doing a simple app, I have an edittext field and a button, the button has an onclick event. The code is as shown below:

```
private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1;  

public void doLaunchContactPicker(View view) {  
    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  
            Contacts.CONTENT_URI);  
    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);  
}
```

I am calling contacts picker activity, when I select a contact I want to populate the name of the contact in the edittext field.

The code for this as shown below:

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
  {   
     String contactname = "";  
     // use the contact provider to get the contact details
     Uri result = data.getData();  
     Cursor  cursor = getContentResolver().query(result, null, null, null, null);
     int idx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
     contactname = cursor.getString(idx);
     EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);  
     name.setText(contactname);
     cursor.close();       
  }
```

All this code is included in the `onCreate()` of the main activity.

When I run the app in emulator and click on the button I am getting contact list (I have created 3 contacts in the emulator). when I select a contact I am getting an error in DDMS. the error is:

```
06-09 19:24:16.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7158): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `cursor.moveToFirst()` first. A cursor's first position is always -1.